# How to manage raid devices doing automated checks?

Tags: 20.04, raid, mdadm

I've got a RAID6 set up, and every now and then it does a check, and during that check, it seems I cannot write to the entire array.

Details:

```
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10]
md0 : active raid6 sda1[0] sdh1[7] sdf1[5] sdc1[2] sdb1[1] sdd1[3] sde1[4] sdg1[6]
      93754475520 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [8/8] [UUUUUUUU]
      [================>....]  check = 82.8% <REDACTED> finish=278.4min speed=160704K/sec
      bitmap: 0/117 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

And the output of:

`$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0`

```
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Mon May  2 22:14:43 2022
        Raid Level : raid6
        Array Size : <REDACTED>
     Used Dev Size : <REDACTED>
      Raid Devices : 8
     Total Devices : 8
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Tue Nov 14 17:28:03 2023
             State : clean, checking
    Active Devices : 8
   Working Devices : 8
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

      Check Status : 83% complete

              Name : <REDACTED>
              UUID : <REDACTED>
            Events : 189274

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       2       8       33        2      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       3       8       49        3      active sync   /dev/sdd1
       4       8       65        4      active sync   /dev/sde1
       5       8       81        5      active sync   /dev/sdf1
       6       8       97        6      active sync   /dev/sdg1
       7       8      113        7      active sync   /dev/sdh1
```

This renders the machine unusable for the period that this check is happening. I'd like to avoid that, but don't know how. All results I'm finding is saying to just let it finish.

I'd like to arrive at a situation where the array doesn't become unusable for hours at a time.

Comment: I know that you can pause the checks to allow you to write to the array before you can restart the checks.  During the checks though it needs to go into a read-only state to prevent the checksums from getting corrupted because of a new write to the drive.  I am not in front of my system right now to get all the information, but that is what I can remember off the top of my head.